# Debugging 2-legged OAuth2 in Go

Tags: debugging, go, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am working on implementing a client library for a remote API which uses 2-legged OAuth2 for authentication.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2/clientcredentials"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
)

type SpecialClient struct {
    *http.Client
}

func NewClient(cid, cis string) *SpecialClient {
    tconf := clientcredentials.Config{
        ClientID:     cid,
        ClientSecret: cis,
        TokenURL:     "http://some.remote.resource/token",
    }

    c := tconf.Client(context.Background())
    return &SpecialClient{c}
}

func main() {
    c := NewClient("clientID", "clientSecret")
    c.Get("http://some.remote.resource/path/to/resource")
}
```

It is extremely straightforward. Right now, I think the remote API's OAuth2 implementation is broken, as it's not returning a token properly according to [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749). I'm trying to debug the client creation with `golang.org/x/oauth2/clientcredentials`, but I cannot determine at which point a token is fetched from the token URL. I've stepped through almost 100 calls with [delve](https://github.com/derekparker/delve), and I do not see the client creating a new request to fetch a token. Is there a way I can review the request created by the `*http.Client` used to retrieve the token?

Comment: Try calling `tconf.Client.Token`; does that give you a valid token?

Comment: `tconf.Client.Token undefined (type func("golang.org/x/net/context".Context) *http.Client has no field or method Token)` was the error I got. However, `tok, err := tconf.Token(context.Background())` returned the same error message I am trying to debug.